# Обновить данные в базе во всех таблицах

Tags: sql, база-данных, update

Необходимо поменять значение столбца, который находится во нескольких (более 100) таблицах в базе.
Все таблицы можно выбрать:

```
select table_name as таблицы 
 from information_schema.columns 
 where column_name={название столбца}
```

Как теперь заменить значения в этих столбцах, по которым был поиск?

Comment: Ну теперь в процедуре беги курсором по строке, динамически строй текст запроса на обновление для каждой таблицы и выполняй.

Comment: Наличие подобного столбца в стольких таблицах мягко намекает, что что-то не так в вашей структуре данных..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

## Пример решения для Oracle PL/SQL

Подготовка данных (для примера)

```
create table table_test(DESCR varchar2(255));
insert into table_test values ('NAME AAA');
insert into table_test values ('NAME BBB');
```

В таблице:

```
select * from table_test;

DESCR
------
NAME AAA
NAME BBB
```

Выборка всех таблиц в схеме "my_scheme" и стобцом 'DESCR'

```
select * from all_tab_columns 
where owner = 'my_scheme' and column_name = 'DESCR'
```

Обновление данных (PL/SQL)

```
begin
 dbms_output.put_line('== start ==');
 for rec in (
    select * from all_tab_columns
    where owner = 'my_scheme' and column_name = 'DESCR'
 )
 loop                          
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
     'update '||rec.owner||'.'||rec.table_name||'
      set '||rec.column_name||' = replace('||rec.column_name||',''AAA'',''CCC'')';
   dbms_output.put_line('* Обновлено - '|| rec.table_name||'.'||rec.column_name);  
 end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line('== end ==');
 commit;
end;
```

Вывод в DBMS:

```
== start ==
* Обновлено - TABLE_TEST.DESCR
== end ==
```

Результат:

```
select * from table_test;

DESCR
------
NAME CCC
NAME BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сформировать запросы для обновления каждой таблицы динамически, и выполнить их с помощью sp_executesql

Comment: Вообще-то из вопроса никак не очевидно, что у автора именно MS SQL Server, а sp_executesql есть только в нём. :)